# preg_match_all parse problem with end word

Tags: preg-match-all

```
$content = '<!--title:FAST-->
<iframe src="https://example.com/38d6996f11" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
asd
<!--nextpage--><!--title:FEM-->
<iframe src="https://example.com/38d6996f11" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

<!--nextpage--><!--title:DRIVE-->
<iframe src="https://example.com/38d6996f11" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

<!--nextpage--><!--title:MOLY-->
<iframe src="https://example.com/38d6996f11" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

qwe';

preg_match_all('@<!--title:(.*?)-->(.*?)(?<!--nextpage)@is', $content, $content_out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($content_out);
```

i have problem with this preg_match_all regex,
this code gives just three parts. i need them all (four part with words; not just iframes), someone can help?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `<!--title:(.*?)-->\R<iframe[^>]*></iframe>(?:\R+(\w+))?`  https://regex101.com/r/Ple1oC/1

Comment: hello, thanks for it but no i am try to parse between <!title and <!-nextpage inner codes. last part doesnt have <!--nextpage code and because of it this code just only gives three part codes. i think we need the just if exists [<!--nextpage] thing. but i don't know how ?

Comment: and if you try to delete iframe code at first part you can see doesn't parse well, i need exactly parse between <!--title:(.*?)-->(.*?)<!--nextpage--> with part names and inner codes

Comment: You are trying to match the iframes between title and nextpage? Parsing html with regex is [a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Perhaps it would be better to use [DOMdocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: not just for iframes, i am just trying to parse <!--title:(.*?)-->(.*?)<!--nextpage--> for inner strings or codes. iframe was just for example. the <!--nextpage--> thing isnt place at last part. just we need use <!--nextpage--> with indistinct like (?:<!--nextpage-->) but this not work. domdocument for only html tags :( what i need example: <!--title:(.*?)-->(.*?)(?:<!--nextpage-->)?

Comment: You mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/JZgIRz/1

Comment: yes thanks alot. its working !

Comment: It means end of line/string. It depends on the multiline setting. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html